# Change a font of titles in document

Tags: fonts, titles, overleaf

I want to change the fonts of titles in my thesis. Currently, I am writing in
[This template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/richtlinien-zur-ausarbeitung-von-bachelor-und-masterarbeiten/sptsvyhnfvhq)

As per overleaf documentation,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Gubert Farnsworth}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...

\section{Second Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\end{document}
```

My document is like this. I have changed the fonts in the text by using `\usepackage{tgpagella}`. But I am not able to change the fonts of titles i.e. Introduction or Sections to `tgpagella`. Please suggest me what can I do? In the photo samples of my document. [image]

Comment: Could you provide the complete code which gives that output? Simply adding `\usepackage{tgpagella}`, the code above produces the expected result.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, yes I have attached the template in which I am writing. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/richtlinien-zur-ausarbeitung-von-bachelor-und-masterarbeiten/sptsvyhnfvhq    .Here, in this template in settings.txt I have updated the package `\usepackage{tgpagella}`. But it did not change the title fonts.

Comment: if the template is in the german language please refer to this template. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/guidance-on-the-preparation-of-degree-theses/zvbvgkspxsvh @Ivan

Comment: I can not access to overleaf, sorry. Somewhere in the template there is a package or a command that set a different font for the sectoin titles

Comment: If the template you refer to is the file `arbeit.tex`, then you have to give a look to the `\input{einstellungen}` file. Anyway try to put `\usepackage{tgpagella}` after this `\input` command

Comment: Hmm. No it's not working that way. I tried 'not so good' option, where I changed, `\section{Introduction}` to `\section{\fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont Introduction}}`.But it's not a good or permanent solution.

Comment: You should provide a minimal working example to get a better answer. But if your temporary solution works you could also try to use: `\usepackage{sectsty}\allsectionsfont{\fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119902/discussion-between-ivan-and-aditya-parikh).